# How to remove #N/A created from UDF array formula

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a VBA UDF where it returns 2D array of data. However, I want to automatically removed all the "#N/A" produced when the data returned is lesser than the total rows by array formula.

[image]

For example, in the above picture. Since the returned data is up to row 164 only, but my UDF is from row 0 up to row 180, what happen is the data from row 165 to 180 will be #N/A.
Is there a way on how to make it empty or just blank cell?

Comment: Why don't you share your UDF?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346613/udf-returns-array-that-is-too-large-or-too-small-for-the-calling-range
I found the solution here. Thanks. 
Have similar situation.